# Entering (input/scanner) two same numbers consecutively to break a loop "while" Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am a new-bee in java, I have a problem that i cant figure out to compare previous entered number(int) with next one continuously and I need to write a program that repeatedly reads numbers from the user’s keyboard. The program stops looping when the user types the same number twice in a row.

Thanks in advance for your kind guidance.

Here’s a sample run of the program:
5
13
21
5
4
5
5
Done!

Following was my unsuccessful effort :)

> Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>           System.out.println("Enter Numbers");

```
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    x = input.nextInt();
    y = input.nextInt();
    while (x != y) {

        x = input.nextInt();
        y = input.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Done!!!!!!!");
    input.close();
```

Comment: Just store the previous value in a variable and check whether or not the new value is the same as the previous value. If so: stop loop, if not, update previous value and re-enter the loop.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please share a code with your attempting to achieve the result. Meanwhile please read a reference [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You code will only compare after entering a set of two numbers and only comparing these numbers to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import java.util.Scanner;

public class OngoingPractice {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int previous, current;

    previous = keyboard.nextInt();
    current = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (current != previous) {
        previous = current;
        current = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Done!");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop to read number from console and stop if previous nubmer equals to current one. As marker of first number you can use e.g. `null` value of `Integer prv` (as alternative, you can use `boolean isFirstLine` flag for first line or `res.isEmpty()`).

```
public static List<Integer> receiveNumbers() {
    List<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();
    Integer prv = null;

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (true) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();

            if (prv != null && prv == num)
                break;

            res.add(num);
            prv = num;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes. This is `Integer` but **not** `int`

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, this is not enough. If `prv == null`, then `if(prv == num)` throws **NPE**, because `if(prv == num)` is `if(prv.intValue() == num)`

Comment: Sorry, I was missing that

Answer (score -1):

Remember the last entered data in one variable and check  it with the current data. If both matches, break the loop.

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);            
        String previousNumber="";
        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
          int number = scan.nextInt(); 
          if(!previousNumber.equals("") && number==Integer.parseInt(previousNumber)) { 
            break;
          }else {
            System.out.println(number);
          }            
          previousNumber=number+"";
        }
```

Comment: What if first number will be 0?

Comment: Condition can be handled

Answer (score -1):

Just use an infinite while loop and break if the new `int` is equal to previous one. As a suggestion you should show how you tried.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    Integer j = null;
    boolean flag = false;
    while(true) {
        i = sc.nextInt();
        if(j==null) {j=i; flag = true;}
        if(j==i&&!flag) {
            System.out.println("Done");
            break;}
        j=i;
        flag = false;
    }
```

Edited : if first one is -1, it won't work as in the comment. so I modified some.

Comment: what happens if the first number entered is `-1`

Comment: @ScaryWombat My modification should do the job.